# Laravel - What does php artisan view:clear do?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-artisan

I run a command `php artisan view:clear`, as I followed a tutorial on custom 404 pages in Laravel, and as explained, the command Clears all compiled view files, further on I looked it up in laravel docs and it said that it removes the cache from view files. The reason why im asking this is because

- im not sure if this effects my view files
- Will they stay the same?
- Did i remove something important running this command?
- What are these cache files for?
- Will this effect my future work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This command basically just clears out all cached views.

Rather than loading your view every time, a cached copy can be stored in your storage folder. View caching is done because blade compiling each time is a waste of time, as blade obviously turns the template in to a proper PHP file.

By running `php artisan view:clear` you simply clear out all the cached views, and so next time the blade view is loaded it will be compiled again rather than pulling it from the cache.

> im not sure if this effects my view files

This does not effect the views themselves, it simply clears the cached copies.

> Will they stay the same?

Your views themselves will stay the same, yes.

> Did i remove something important running this command?

Only the cached copies of your views. These will simply be compiled again when the page is loaded.

> What are these cache files for?

To prevent blade having to compile every time it is called, it can be done just once to prevent wasting this time.

> Will this effect my future work?

Not at all.

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering, i was really worried, never running unfamiliar commands again! I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes (StackOverflow says that i have to wait) :)

Comment: No worries, glad it clarified things for you.

Comment: `View:clear` is useful when developing or playing around with blade directives.